# After upgrade to 15.04 system does not boot from encrypted disk

Tags: boot, upgrade, encryption, 15.04, lvm

The system was installed with LVM encryption, so it used to ask for a passphrase before booting.

Now, the boot process fails with the following:

```
Gave up waiting for root device.  Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-9ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Of course the system is correct, /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root does indeed not exist right now. Here's blkid's output:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="e3106b58-2400-4c49-abdb-967b1718d3ec" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="00082db5-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="0e81cba9-2bae-4450-9661-e7615782f412" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="00082db5-02"
```

Where /dev/sda1 used to be /boot and /dev/sda5 is the rest of the disk (encrypted).

How do I proceed from here? (And what went wrong? Can it happen again?)

Thanks, cd.